# How to generate and view dashboard generated reports in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In windows, using the command "jmeter -n -t [test JMX file] -l [test log file] -e -o " to generate the dashboard result doesn't execute and shows the error.

Comment: What error do you get ? can you show the full command line your execute ?

Comment: Executing above command it says, "jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: I used following command:-
      jmeter -n -t C:\Users\Freeware Sys\Desktop\JmeterTestCases
\VisitingAllPages.jmx -l C:\Users\Freeware Sys\Documents\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\j
meter.log -e -o C:\Users\Freeware Sys\Desktop\DashboardReport\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 problems:

- first ensure that you have a Java 7 or 8 installed and that this command works:

> java -version

- second, change your current directory to be in the jmeter_home\bin folder (C:\Users\Freeware Sys\Documents\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin) ad run command from there

Comment: Thanks. I followed above processes but still getting some different problem. This time executing command "jmeter -n -t D:\VisitingAllPages.jmx -l jmeter.log -e -o D:\DashboardReport" to create the report it gives below error:-

Creating summariser <summary>
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Results file:jmeter.log is not empty

Comment: Can you open another question with full details ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to generate report dashboard instead of using jmeter.log file.

1. Add Simple Data Writer from Listeners.
2. Provide your path, where you want to generate like it could be in csv file or xls file etc.

**Note:** Remember one thing you should not create a file whether it could be csv,xls etc file because Simple Data writer automatically creates the Test results file as provided location.Then simple run your test plan and try to generate report dashboard with command prompt with generated Test Result file. You can read more configurations [here](http://learn-jmeter.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-generate-jmeter-report-dashboard.html).

Here it has given complete step by step details for generating Report Dashboard in Jmeter.